# How can I get the path, that Word document will be saved to?

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I have a program that manages Word documents. At one point, I'm saving a document:

```
var document = applicationWord.Documents.Add(GetTemplatePath(type));
document.SaveAs(path);
```

In another place, I'm handling the DocumentBeforeSave event:

```
void DocumentBeforeSave(Document doc, ref bool saveAsUi, ref bool cancel)
{
    var documentPath = doc.FullName;
    ...
}
```

The problem is, at this moment the documents FullName is Document1, as it's not saved yet.

Is there a way to obtain the path in which document will be saved...?

Answer (score 0):

The [SaveAs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836084.aspx) family of methods states:

> **The default is the current folder and file name**. If the document has
>   never been saved, the default name is used (for example, Doc1.doc). If
>   a document with the specified file name already exists, the document
>   is overwritten without prompting the user.

As long as FullName is `SomeName` you can assume current folder, otherwise `FullName` property will hold the full path (if you have used it during `SaveAs` call)

Comment: I am providing a path to the file. It won't be the current folder. I want to retrieve the path I provided from Document object, if it's possible. If not, I will attach to custom AfterSave event and go from there...